# I misheard man’s voice and I heard woman’s voice correctly

Tags: phrase-choice

If I misheard the man’s voice and I heard the woman’s voice, can I call this single action both ‘incorrect hearing (of man)’ and ‘correct hearing (of woman)’?

Comment: You’d say that you misheard the man and heard the woman correctly.

Comment: You misheard the man but you understood the woman (does not mention 'voice' baggage).

Comment: @WeatherVane To be technical "heard correctly" is not the same as "understood".

Comment: @DJClayworth Not sure that's helpful to the OP. I think it's clear enough in this context that "understand" carries the same meaning as "hear correctly"

Answer (score 0):

You’d say that you misheard the man and heard the woman correctly.

There is no need to mention "voice" and your version "incorrect hearing" is not idiomatic.

Comment: I'd also suggest using "but" rather than "and".